docx2pdf set permissions on docx fie
I am calling an api to download a docx file which I save locally. I then want convert it to PDF. When I run docx2pdf on the file, I get a pop-up stating that MS Word needs permissions. What can I do to automate this step and remove the popup so a user is not involved? Should I set appropriate permissions on the file when I download it? What are those permissions? I tried chmod but no luck.

this is excerpts from my code:
response = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)

if response.status_code == 200:
 content = response.content
 with open("ex.docx", "wb") as file:
   file.write(content)
 os.chmod("ex.docx", 0o0777)
convert("ex.docx", "ex.pdf")



you could try to use different library like
https://pypi.org/project/python-docx/
https://pypi.org/project/pdfkit/ 

First you open the file with python-docx and then parse to pdf. This should not use MS word so you will not have this pop up.
